# Eevee won't properly render a model that I got online

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to use a free model that I found online in Blender 2.8, but am having a hard time getting it to render properly using Eevee. It's an eye model and it appears it won't render a certain cornea effect, whereas the model is properly rendered when using Cycles. Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

[image: Eevee]

[image: Cycles]

Comment: You're probably doing nothing wrong. EEVEE and Cycles are two different render engines and will produce different results. You will have to adjust your node setup for each.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need to adjust your material blend mode on the cornea material, the iris and eye should be set to opaque, and cornea to alpha blend or add. Note that having two layers of alpha blend will cause sorting issues. Also you might want to try toggling backface culling.

[image: eevee blend modes]